# Titlesec package is indenting space for \chapter listing in Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titlesec, titletoc

I am using both the `titletoc` and `titlesec` packages to format my chapters. I am using a special font and the following command:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering \normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\centering \vspace*{-2.6cm}\chaptertitlename \hspace{1.9pt} {\fontsize{29}{38}\selectfont\thechapter \\
        \vspace*{-1.5cm}\hspace*{-0.15cm}{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21A9} \hspace{6.94cm} {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21AA}}}{10pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0pt}\titlerule\vspace{1.7pt}\titlerule\vspace{-20pt}]
```

But I get the following result in the contents page:

[image]

How can I make the indentation go back to what it used to be in normal LaTeX in which the chapter is less indented than a section that is less indented than a subsection, and so on?

As I was writing a minimal Working example, it seems that the abntex package has something to do with this conflict, but It does not appear to be a standard formating style in abntex

Here is a Minimally working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{abntex2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering \normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\centering \vspace*{-2.6cm}\chaptertitlename \hspace{1.9pt} 
{\fontsize{29}{38}\selectfont\thechapter \\
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}\hspace*{-0.15cm}{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21A9} \hspace{6.94cm} {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21AA}}}{10pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0pt}\titlerule\vspace{1.7pt}\titlerule\vspace{-20pt}]

\begin{document}


\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Objetivos}

\section{Justificativa e Revisão da Literatura}

\section{Metodologia}

\section{Cronograma}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend your fragment into a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please? You are leaving it up to the people you want an answer from to write the entire MWE document (that may not accurately reflect your setup)

Comment: As I was writing a minimal Working example, it seems that the abntex package has something to do with this conflict, but It does not appear to be a standard formating style in abntex.

Comment: Are you using the outdated version of `abntex` or the new one here? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2. Could be the issue, the old one has been replaced, try `\usepackage{abntex2}` instead and edit into your question if that doesn't solve the issue so it can be narrowed down :)

Comment: I am using the new one, see the MWE.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I thought it was a package and not a class. Hope someone can answer!

Answer (score 1):

The class `abntex2` load the `memoir` class and uses the tools it provides to customize the document. It is a well-known fact that `memoir` and `titlesec` are not compatible.

From the `abntex2` manual: "The `abntex2` class produces a summary constructed similar to the recommended example
by ABNT NBR 6027: 2012. It is the default option."

While this custom table of contents is enabled automatically, it can be controlled through the `summary= option` of the `\documentclass` declaration.

`summary=traditional` uses the  style of `memoir` summaries.

This option should be used in case of additional customization of the summary.

The same consideration goes for customizing chapter titles: use the tools provided by `memoir` to do so. See [Memoir Chapter Styles](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles?lang=en)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%\usepackage{hyperref}% already loaded by the class <<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering \normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\centering \vspace*{-2.6cm}\chaptertitlename \hspace{1.9pt} 
    {\fontsize{29}{38}\selectfont\thechapter \\
        \vspace*{-1.5cm}\hspace*{-0.15cm}{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21A9} \hspace{6.94cm} {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \char"21AA}}}{10pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{0pt}\titlerule\vspace{1.7pt}\titlerule\vspace{-20pt}]

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \chapter{Objetivos}
    
    \section{Justificativa e Revisão da Literatura}
    
    \section{Metodologia}
    
    \section{Cronograma}
        
\end{document}
```

Used in the example `abntex2.cls    2018/11/24 v-1.9.7 abnTeX2`

Comment: But when using abntex2 by itself it does not display the summary as it was being displayed with titlesec, is it because of a conflict in the moment of compilation? Because they aren't compatible?

Comment: @Felipe Dilho The class `abntex2` load the `memoir` class and uses the tools it provides to customize the document. `memoir` and `titlesec` are not fully compatible.